# ¿Como manejar la finalizacion de un subscribe?

Tags: javascript, firebase, async, angular11

El problema surge cuando requiero actualizar un objeto traído de la base de datos d Firebase. En la primera parte esta el uso del servicio para consultar un elemento en especifico y en la segunda parte el uso del servicio para actualizar el elemento. Cuando se ejecuta la primera parte el objeto queda indefinido hasta que cargue desde Firebase, sin embargo es requerido el objeto para la segunda parte. ¿Como hago para manejar la finalización del suscribe?

**factura.component.ts**

```
Actualizar(){  
var canchaX : Cancha

this.canchaService.getCancha(this.reserva.$key).subscribe(async (canchasSnapshot) =>{
  
  canchaX = await canchasSnapshot.payload.data() as Cancha
  canchaX.$key = "F3q4vOTF7eOPpXttkLId"
  canchaX.reservas.push("DATO ACTUALIZADOx2")
  
  
})
this.canchaService.updateCancha(this.reserva.$key , canchaX!).then(()=>{
  console.log("Actualizado")

})
}
```

E error esta cuando el **newObject** se encuentra *undefined* y se ejecuta el método *updateObject*

**ERROR**

> ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: undefined (found in document objects/F3q4vOTF7eOPpXttkLId)

Answer (score 0):

Has probado poner el `updateCancha` antes de terminar la subscripción:

```
Actualizar(){
    var canchaX: Cancha

    this.canchaService.getCancha(this.reserva.$key).subscribe(async (canchasSnapshot) => {

        canchaX = await canchasSnapshot.payload.data() as Cancha
        canchaX.$key = "F3q4vOTF7eOPpXttkLId"
        canchaX.reservas.push("DATO ACTUALIZADOx2")

        this.canchaService.updateCancha(this.reserva.$key, canchaX!).then(() => {
            console.log("Actualizado")
        })

    })
}
```

O quizas utilizar la función que se ejecuta cuando termina la subscripcion

```
Actualizar(){
    var canchaX: Cancha

    this.canchaService.getCancha(this.reserva.$key).subscribe(async (canchasSnapshot) => {

        canchaX = await canchasSnapshot.payload.data() as Cancha
        canchaX.$key = "F3q4vOTF7eOPpXttkLId"
        canchaX.reservas.push("DATO ACTUALIZADOx2")

    }, (error) => {
        // Si sucede algun error   
    }, () => {
        // Esto sucede cuando finaliza la subscripcion
        this.canchaService.updateCancha(this.reserva.$key, canchaX!).then(() => {
            console.log("Actualizado")
        })
    })
```

}

O utilizando el operador `first`

```
Actualizar(){
var canchaX: Cancha

this.canchaService.getCancha(this.reserva.$key).pipe(first()).subscribe(async (canchasSnapshot) => {

    canchaX = await canchasSnapshot.payload.data() as Cancha
    canchaX.$key = "F3q4vOTF7eOPpXttkLId"
    canchaX.reservas.push("DATO ACTUALIZADOx2")

    this.canchaService.updateCancha(this.reserva.$key, canchaX!).then(() => {
        console.log("Actualizado")
    })

})
```

}

Comment: En el primer caso si lo probé. pero me ocurre que se actualiza de manera infinita y no se porque ocurre. es decir el arreglo `canchaX.reservas` actualiza n veces el dato nuevo. :c.
En el segundo caso no se ejecuta el bloque  cuando finaliza la suscripción. es como si la suscripción quedara abierta.

Comment: Si ese es un complique con los observables, no es bueno que queden abiertos. Depronto te tocaría crear otro metodo en el servicio, que solo devuelva una respuesta. Eso te tocaría buscarlo también en firebase o intenta con el operador `first`, te quedaría así `this.canchaService.getCancha(this.reserva.$key).pipe(first()).subscribe(async .........`, puedes ver su [Documentación aquí](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/first) voy a agregartelo en la respuesta.